# Функция, которая даёт каждый раз отличное число от предыдущего, на основе массива из чисел

Tags: javascript

Я сделал класс `RandomNumber`, при его инициализации ему даётся на вход массив из чисел.
В конструкторе сохраняется этот массив

```js
constructor(numbers) {
  this.numbers = numbers.slice();
}
```

Я хотел сделать функцию в классе `nextNumber`, которая при вызове всегда даёт следующее число, которое отлично от предыдущего
К примеру: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 будет, если в класс на вход дали массив из `[0, 1]`
Но мой код работает не так. Почему-то `1` никогда не повторяется, а 0 часто (а числа вообще не должны повторяться)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
class RandomNumber {

  constructor(numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers.slice();
  }

  random(numbers) { // генерация рандомного числа на основе длины массива
    const randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    const randomNumber = numbers[randomIdx];
    return {num: randomNumber, idx: randomIdx};
  };

  nextNumber() {
    const numbers = this.numbers.slice();
    let randomNumber = this.random(numbers);

    if (this.lastRdnNumber && this.lastRdnNumber.num === randomNumber.num) {
      // this.lastRdnNumber cуществует и прошлое число равняется текущему сгенерированному
      numbers.splice(this.lastRdnNumber.idx, 1); // вырезать число из массива, которое уже было
      randomNumber = this.random(numbers);
    }
  
    this.lastRdnNumber = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber.num;
  }
}

const numbers = [1, 0];
const randomNumber = new RandomNumber(numbers);

for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log(randomNumber.nextNumber());
}
```

Comment: Ошибка здесь: `numbers.splice(this.lastRdnNumber.idx, 1);`. В текущем массиве `numbers` в позиции `randomNumber.idx` находится число, равное числу сгенерированному на предыдущем шаге. Вы хотите его вырезать из массива, но вырезаете почему число в позиции `this.lastRdnNumber.idx`

Comment: Если на предыдущем шаге так совпало, что массив `numbers` усекался (т.е. вы урезали его до одного элемента), тогда на текущем шаге значение `this.lastRdnNumber.idx` гарантированно будет равно нулю (ну, при условии, что в `numbers` изначально только два элемента).

Comment: @wololo точно, благодарю! Оформите ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по совету `@wololo` надо было вырезать то число, которое я придумал, а не прошлое:

```js
numbers.splice(randomNumber.idx, 1);
```

```js
class RandomNumber {

  constructor(numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers.slice();
  }

  random(numbers) { // генерация рандомного числа на основе длины массива
    const randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    const randomNumber = numbers[randomIdx];
    return {num: randomNumber, idx: randomIdx};
  };

  nextNumber() {
    const numbers = this.numbers.slice();
    let randomNumber = this.random(numbers);

    if (this.lastRdnNumber && this.lastRdnNumber.num === randomNumber.num) {
      // this.lastRdnNumber cуществует и прошлое число равняется текущему сгенерированному
      numbers.splice(randomNumber.idx, 1); // вырезать число из массива, которое уже было
      randomNumber = this.random(numbers);
    }
  
    this.lastRdnNumber = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber.num;
  }
}

const numbers = [1, 0];
const randomNumber = new RandomNumber(numbers);

for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log(randomNumber.nextNumber());
}
```